# How can i submit customKeyboard Application in appstore?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I created custom keyboard application.I need to upload it in appstore but there ate some error when i upload it in appstore.
[image]

please give me solution if any one have.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create an provision profile in your apple account and register it in the iTunes Connect?

Comment: Do you have apple developer account and certificates and profiles created ?

Comment: It's is clearly stated "No matching provision found"! What more you need to know

Comment: Do some googling before you post anything like this, here is the link from which you may get how to upload app in appstore:- http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1

Comment: yes, already created provision profile in my apple account. and also register in itune Connect .

Comment: here is provision profile. first is "com.app.emojiKeyboard" and for custome keyboard "com.app.emojiKeyboard.keyboard"